# Check for newest folder in a directory with VB, then go to that directory and repeat the process

Tags: vb.net

I am very new to VB

i am trying to write a script in VB that checks a particular directory for the newest folder (or the last one to be modified), and then go into that folder and do the same thing again. So i was wondering how i should go about doing this? i already have a script that goes to the last folder alphabetically but i need to know how to actually make it choose the latest folder?

script:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim dir As String
        Dim dir2 As String
        Dim fil As String

        For Each dir In Directory.GetDirectories("\\alinta.net.int\alintadata\SOP\mdl database\Weekly Readings")
            Console.WriteLine(dir)
            Dim lat As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(dir)
            Console.WriteLine(lat.LastAccessTime)
        Next

        For Each dir2 In Directory.GetDirectories(dir)
            Console.WriteLine(dir2)
            Dim lat2 As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(dir2)
            Console.WriteLine(lat2.LastAccessTime)
        Next

        For Each fil In Directory.GetFiles(dir2, "*.txt")
            Console.WriteLine(fil)
        Next



        Console.WriteLine("...")
        Console.ReadLine()


    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: vbscript?  so why the VB.NET tag?  I dont see a question... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So what is your actual question?  You want us to do it for you?

Comment: I'm not asking for you to do it for me, i spose my question is How would you go about doing this??

Comment: This is not VBScript. Do you want a VBScript version?

Comment: So you want to recursively go through all nested folders, and return exactly one, which is the latest? What if there are two with the same date?